# Author social media aren't shown on the page

Tags: functions, author, social-sharing, list-authors

I'm trying to show the authors social medias on the page but they aren't showed at all.

Here is the code that I have so far

```
$website = $user->user_url;
if($user->user_url != '') { 
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $user->user_url, '<i class="icon-home"></i>'); 
}
$twitter = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'twitter_profile', true);
if($twitter != '') {  
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $twitter, '<i class="icon-twitter"></i>'); 
}
$facebook = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'facebook_profile', true);
if($facebook != '') { 
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $facebook, '<i class="icon-facebook"></i>');
}
$google = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'google_profile', true);
if($google != ''){
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $google, '<i class="icon-google"></i>');
}
$linkedin = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'linkedin_profile', true);
if($linkedin != ''){ 
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $linkedin, '<i class="icon-linkedin"></i>');
}
```

Only the `Website` is visible. Any idea where is the mistake here?

Answer (score 0):

Try This for IF :

```
if(!empty($user->user_url)) { 
   // OUTPUT
}
```

All Code

```
$website = $user->user_url;
if(!empty($user->user_url)) { 
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $user->user_url, '<i class="icon-home"></i>'); 
}
$twitter = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'twitter_profile', true);
if(!empty($twitter)) {  
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $twitter, '<i class="icon-twitter"></i>'); 
}
$facebook = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'facebook_profile', true);
if(!empty($facebook)) { 
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $facebook, '<i class="icon-facebook"></i>');
}
$google = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'google_profile', true);
if(!empty($google)){
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $google, '<i class="icon-google"></i>');
}
$linkedin = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'linkedin_profile', true);
if(!empty($linkedin)){ 
   printf('<a href="%s">%s</a>', $linkedin, '<i class="icon-linkedin"></i>');
}
```

**EDIT**

**Previously, you had to add code in the function according to your needs.**

Example

```
<?php
//CREATE  CUSTOM USER DATA
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'facebook_custom_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'facebook_custom_extra_profile_fields' );

function facebook_custom_extra_profile_fields( $user ) { ?>

    <h3><?php echo esc_html__('Facebook URL','text-domain');?></h3>

    <table class="form-table">

        <tr>
            <th><label for="twitter"><?php echo esc_html__('Facebook URL','text-domain');?></label></th>

            <td>
                <input type="text" name="facebook_profile" id="facebook_profile" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'facebook_profile', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" /><br />
                <span class="description"><?php echo esc_html__('Please enter Facebook URL.','text-domain');?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
<?php }


//SAVE CUSTOM USER DATA

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'facebook_custom_save_extra_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'facebook_custom_save_extra_profile_fields' );

function facebook_custom_save_extra_profile_fields( $user_id ) {

    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;

    update_user_meta( $user_id, 'facebook_profile', $_POST['facebook_profile'] );
}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks but still doesn't show socials. Only the `user_url` is shown as before

Comment: Have you made a custom user data for data input for each social media?

Comment: Sorry, but why I need custom data input? I'm logging in the admin area and I can see/add the social medias directly for each user on their profile

Comment: that means you are using a plugin, what plugin is used?

Comment: This is not a plugin, it is native function of wordpress. If you go to Dashboard->Users and choose Edit for some user then you can see that you can add `Website`, `Facebook profile URL`, etc for the user.

Comment: Found it! The fields aren't `twitter_profile`, `facebook_profile`, etc, but `twitter`, `facebook`.. etc. So silly.

Comment: There is no such thing in WordPress defaults. Except doing your own customization, default theme, or plugin, say using what theme?